# Prevent old images displaying on same component before new data loads

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

### Issue:

I have an item detail component that displays a few images.

When a user has viewed one detail page, then views a second, the images from the first are shown for a split second before the others load in.

I have a spinner which loads while I get data from the API, but it stops loading when the data arrives, but before the images fulling load in, which results in the problem I described above.

### Tried

I have reasons for why I do not want to remove my Vuex data of those images on `destroyed()` of the component, but this strategy does work.

### What I need

An alternate strategy to preventing images' `src` from using old data?

### Project Details

Vue 2 + Vuex / Axios

Comment: why not clear it? perhaps set a value in the store that image/data is stale, then add another check before showing image and make value unstale once you pulled in the new data, extra steps over simply clearing it

Comment: I just went through and selectively removed the images I didn't want. Although I didn't want to wipe all data, I was able to wipe just the image data and then run it on `unmounted()` in the component I wanted to clear.

This seems to have worked, thanks.